# Некорректное отображение TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-textview

Есть xml в который включен следующий `LinearLayout`:

**portion_picker.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="64dp"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/portion_minus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_minus"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/potion_count_text_view"
        android:layout_width="64dp"         
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" //64dp
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="54sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/portion_plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

В превью выглядит корректно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на реальных устройствах (SGS5, Note 3) `TextView` отображает текст внутри (в моем случае правда это всего лишь одна/две цифры) некорректно - как можно заметить - не по центру (относительно горизонтальной оси), а чуть ниже, думаю это заметно и режет глаз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему происходит смещение текста внутри? В таком отображении это очень критично, прошу подсказать из-за чего происходит данное смещение

Comment: Превью лучше не юзать, а проверять сразу на реальном устройстве. А отцентрировать попробуйте проставив `android:gravity="center_vertical"` для `TextView`

Comment: ПРоисходит потому что размеры (textSize) заданы в относительных единицах, которые разные экраны интерпретируют по своему. Для того чтобы выравнять все по центру нужно использовать такие параметры textView, как layout_gravity (выравнивание textView в layout) и gravity(выравнивание текста внутри textView)

Comment: Я сталкивался с подобной проблемой при использовании Font. Был точно такой же эффект как у вас, но так как он одинаково смещал все элементы, меня спас марджин.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб к сожалению замена с center на center_vertical не помогло

Comment: @iamthevoid совсем не понял вашего совета, что вы хотите этим сообщить, ведь у меня и так используются данные параметры и определены

Comment: @abbath0767, тогда попробуйте `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` для картинок

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii интересный способ - но по моему это какой то лютый костыль который может на разных устройствах отображаться по разному. Но поигравшись с отступами я добился некоторого корректного отображения...но правда это точно работает с одним устройством....

Comment: Если Вы поигрались с отступами, то едва ли чего то добились, поверьте мне - скоро будет устрйоство где все поедет. Может Вам стоит попробовать заменить лайоут на RelativeLayout и сделать выравнивание изображений по центру TextView?

Comment: @iamthevoid нет не помогает. Сам текст отображается не в середине своего поля отображения

Comment: @abbath0767 ну лучшего решения я не нашел, а в нашей компании около десятка разновидных тестовых девайсов, протестил на всех, все было ок. Я бы сказал скорее что это какой то баганый шрифт попался (в моем случае).